# Customizing Vuze(Azereus)

Tags: java, netbeans, vuze

I wish to customize Vuze(Azereus) source code to suit my needs.

Basicly wish to setup a server managed P2P and customize welcome page.

I have downloaded the complete source code (314 mb) with all versions.

I am unable to add it as NetBeans project. There was supposed to be a netbeaned project version of azerus but it is no longer available.

Can anybody help in how to make azereus a NetBean project ready for editing.